# What does [anon] means in pmap linux cmd

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I'am working on an internet home gateway (openwrt, 64 bit). When I execute top, I find that UPNPD process is allocating a huge amount of virtual memory:

```
Mem: 239096K used, 215584K free, 0K shrd, 9652K buff, 39256K cached
CPU:   0% usr   0% sys   0% nic 100% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 0.36 0.41 0.39 1/93 10104
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ %CPU COMMAND
 2196   930 root     S     394m  89%   0% upnpd -f -r
```

--> About 394m 
--> It can reach 1 G!!!

When I execute pmap `pidof upnpd` I found that there are big blocs:

```
# pmap 2196
0000000000400000      88K r-xp  /usr/sbin/upnpd
0000000000426000       4K rw-p  /usr/sbin/upnpd
0000000000427000       4K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000000036d6e000     140K rw-p  [heap]
0000007f78000000     132K rw-p    [ anon ]
**0000007f78021000   65404K ---p    [ anon ]**
0000007f80000000    2596K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f80289000   62940K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f84000000     132K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f84021000   65404K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f88000000     132K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f88021000   65404K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f8c000000     132K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f8c021000   65404K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f90000000     132K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f90021000   65404K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f95adb000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f95adc000     124K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f95afb000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f95afc000     124K rw-p  [stack:2249]
0000007f95b1b000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f95b1c000     124K rw-p  [stack:2248]
0000007f95b3b000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f95b3c000    1020K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f95c3b000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f95c3c000    1020K rw-p  [stack:2246]
0000007f95d3b000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f95d3c000    1020K rw-p  [stack:2245]
0000007f95e3b000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f95e3c000    1020K rw-p  [stack:2244]
0000007f95f3b000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f95f3c000    1020K rw-p  [stack:2243]
0000007f9603b000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f9603c000    1020K rw-p  [stack:2242]
0000007f9613b000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f9613c000    1020K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f9623b000       4K ---p    [ anon ]
0000007f9623c000    1020K rw-p  [stack:2240]
0000007f9633b000    1220K r-xp  /lib/libc-2.22.so
0000007f9646c000      60K ---p  /lib/libc-2.22.so
0000007f9647b000      16K r--p  /lib/libc-2.22.so
0000007f9647f000       8K rw-p  /lib/libc-2.22.so
0000007f96481000      16K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f96485000      84K r-xp  /usr/lib/libgsdf.so.1.0.0
0000007f9649a000      60K ---p  /usr/lib/libgsdf.so.1.0.0
0000007f964a9000       4K rw-p  /usr/lib/libgsdf.so.1.0.0
0000007f964aa000      16K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f964ae000      16K r-xp  /usr/lib/libthreadutil.so.6.0.3
0000007f964b2000      64K ---p  /usr/lib/libthreadutil.so.6.0.3
0000007f964c2000       4K rw-p  /usr/lib/libthreadutil.so.6.0.3
0000007f964c3000      32K r-xp  /usr/lib/libixml.so.2.0.8
0000007f964cb000      64K ---p  /usr/lib/libixml.so.2.0.8
0000007f964db000       4K rw-p  /usr/lib/libixml.so.2.0.8
0000007f964dc000     120K r-xp  /usr/lib/libupnp.so.6.3.2
0000007f964fa000      64K ---p  /usr/lib/libupnp.so.6.3.2
0000007f9650a000       4K rw-p  /usr/lib/libupnp.so.6.3.2
0000007f9650b000       8K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f9650d000      92K r-xp  /lib/libpthread-2.22.so
0000007f96524000      60K ---p  /lib/libpthread-2.22.so
0000007f96533000       4K r--p  /lib/libpthread-2.22.so
0000007f96534000       4K rw-p  /lib/libpthread-2.22.so
0000007f96535000      16K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f96539000     112K r-xp  /lib/ld-2.22.so
0000007f9655f000      16K rw-p    [ anon ]
0000007f96563000       4K r--p  [vvar]
0000007f96564000       4K r-xp  [vdso]
0000007f96565000       4K r--p  /lib/ld-2.22.so
0000007f96566000       8K rw-p  /lib/ld-2.22.so
0000007fd72dd000     132K rw-p  [stack]
```

For your information, Upnpd process creates threads depending on clients connected. I noticed that for each thread created, a bloc of 65404K is mapped, for example: 0000007f90021000   65404K ---p    [ anon ]

Questions:
1- What are the meaning of these blocs?
2- Why we map these blocs for each thread ? 
3- Why when killing a thread, these blocs remains mapped?

Answer (score 4):

`pmap` uses the `proc` filesystem to get information. And below is from `man proc` about a `/proc/[pid]/maps` file:

> What are the meaning of these blocs?

If the pathname field is blank, this is an **anonymous** mapping as obtained via the mmap(2) function.  There is no easy way to coordinate this back to a process's source, short of running it through gdb(1), strace(1), or similar.

The address field is the address space in the process that the mapping occupies.  The perms field is a set of permissions:

```
               r = read
               w = write
               x = execute
               s = shared
               p = private (copy on write)
```

So it seems that the program allocates memory from heap in each of its thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a reserved private memory.

---p permissions mean that this private memory was allocated with PROT_NONE

Reserved memory it's just allocated process virtual address space, not memory.